# ws02 identity server management console

Tags: wso2-identity-server

Hi i am new to ws02 identity server. I would like to go load the management console locally via https://localhost:9443/carbon but the url seems to have some certificate issues (NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID).

Anybody knows whats wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Any out-of-box WSO2 product (or more generally - any web product with SSL running locally) has a bundled self-signed certificate. This certificate by default is not trusted.

You can add this certificate to be trusted (on your local workstation), though easiest, but not the best (long term) solution. When going to production, you MUST provide your own qualified keypair and certificate for SSL (and eventually for signing SAML responses when used).

The keystore used for SSL is configured on the repository/conf/tomat/catalina-server.xml

The keystore used for signing is configured in repository/conf/carbon.xml and in the resident IdP configuration.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS520/Deploying+in+Production
https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Setting+up+Keystores